# Toggle hide() fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to toggle an element quickly?

I have this at the moment:

```
 $('.appearLate, .topMnu').toggle('hide');
```

But it fades gradually by default.
I need it to fade out fast but cant work out how to apply the attribute.

Can someone please tell me how i could do this?

Comment: Why are you passing `'hide'` as argument? The documentation doesn't mention it: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work

```
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').toggle('fast');
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').toggle(100); //pass time in milliseconds
```

or

```
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').fadeOut('fast');
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').fadeOut(100);//pass time in milliseconds
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for the [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function:

```
$(selector).fadeOut('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').toggle(100); //100 being number of milisecconds to perform translation
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').slideToggle('fast');
```

or

```
$('.appearLate, .topMnu').fadeToggle('fast');
```